# Where to find the code that redirects requests on the static page URL to the home page

Tags: theme-development, redirect

As an example, let's say I set my "About Us" page (slug: about-us) as my home page static page. Upon doing this, when someone requests mysite.com/about-us, WordPress does a nice redirect to the home page so that I don't end up with duplicate content of having two pages pointing to the same content.

I'm trying to find where in the core code that this redirect code appears, because I'm trying to emulate the same behavior when using a sticky post as the home page.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Did you have to go the page-template way, or did setting `page_on_front` to the sticky post's ID suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the behavior you describe is not a *redirect* but a *URL rewrite*.

That being said, there's a WordPress [option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference) called `page_on_front` that is set to the page ID of the static page to be used as a front page. This option's value is only relevant if the option `show_on_front` is set to `page` (that happens if you set "Front page displays" to "A static page" in the "Reading" panel).

[image]

Depending on the page you select from the dropdown below that radio box, `page_on_front` is set.

You can however also set options programmatically. The following approach is **untested** and just a quick idea off the top of my head, but it should be possible to simply set this option to the sticky post's ID and be done with it:

```
$sticky_id = // set to post ID you want to display
update_option( 'page_on_front', $sticky_id );
```

Another approach (if this first idea fails) might be to set the front page to a regular static page, assign that page a custom template, leave the page content empty and incorporate a custom loop that grabs the latest sticky post in said page template. That ought to work fo'shizzle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this page will have the best information for you:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

`wp-includes/rewrite.php`